# What is a standard object in java?

Tags: java, string, object

I came across this statement "Java Strings are standard objects with built-in language support" in a book.

I know what objects are, but is there a special point they are trying to make by calling strings "standard objects"? Are they somehow different from other objects? What is a standard object?

Comment: Same as "built-in" or "part of standard Java implementation".

Comment: Not a primitive type?

Comment: [Java String is Special](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html)

Comment: @Pshemo - Is not!!  It just *thinks* it's special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that there is no "special magic" in the language or runtime to support strings. They are [implemented with the normal constructs used for any kind of Object](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html).

And that is true.

However, one has to appreciate that Strings do get a lot of additional support because they are such a commonly used thing:

- String literals in the language
- String interning
- upcoming String backing store deduplication by the garbage collector
- operator overloading (+)
- support in Object serialization stream format

One thing that Strings *don't* get, however, is an overloaded `==` operator. Here they behave just like "standard objects" and a lot of beginners trip over that. If you need a good example how strings are just "standard objects", you can point at the `==` versus `equals` issue.

Answer (score 1):

This reference is probably referring to how strings are implemented in other languages as compositions of character values, instead of literal objects (or types as it might be in some languages).

For instance in C a String is just an array of characters.

In Haskell, a `String` is just a type synonym for a list of `Char` values.

In Java, A `String` object is an actual instance the `String` class *not* just an array of `char` values.